# What is the pumpkin rocket ammo/weapon in Fortnite BR?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I watched a few videos and a saw a strange weapon. It looked like a rocket launcher with an explosive pumpkin as its rocket ammo. It works exactly like the normal one. I even heard that people can ride on it (when someone shoots it you can "fly" with it).

Is this a real weapon / rocket ammo?
Is this a another rocket launcher weapon or a type of ammo?
Can people "ride" on it?
What are the differences between the *normal rocket* and the *pumpkin rocket*?

Comment: You can "ride" regular rockets too, if you time your jump right.

Comment: What are the differences between the normal rocket and the pumpkin rocket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pumpkin rocket launcher was a skin for the rocket launcher that Epic Games released for the Halloween event in Fortnite. This weapon uses the same ammo as the normal rocket launcher and you can ride it. The only difference is that it is larger, so easier to ride, and the sound effect was more Halloween themed, as it had a ghostly laugh whenever you shot the weapon.

Comment: Not worth it for a new answer: The rockets prior to the Halloween event were not ridable and actually the Halloween rockets had a bug that allowed for players to ride. after the event they removed that but due to player demand they added it back

Comment: Is it still in the game now?

Comment: no, it is not currently in the game